# Can't upload larger files to server

Tags: apache-2.4, php.ini, php7

I have a Ubuntu 16.04 server with apache 2.4 and php 7.1. The php.ini has the following settings:

```
max_file_uploads    20
memory_limit    512M
post_max_size   256M
upload_max_filesize 128M
```

Folder permissions are alright, plenty of free space on the hdd (100+ GB)

And still can't upload a file bigger then ~40MB, php keeps throwing error code 3: UPLOAD_ERR_PARTIAL (which means: 'The uploaded file was only partially uploaded.'). No other error or log entry generated.

This driving me nuts. Is there any other variable/system setting i don't know about?

Any help really appreciated!

Comment: Is your disk full?

Comment: No, "plenty of free space on the hdd (100+ GB)"

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem. The apache had a `RequestReadTimeout header=20-40,MinRate=500 body=20-40,MinRate=500` setting which means the request's forced to timeout after max 40 sec... Another thing to watch out for.